# Difference between "with the time" and "over the time"

Tags: prepositions

**The situation will get better "with the time".
The situation will get better "over the time".**

Frequently, I am encompassing these words. Confused!!

Answer (score 1):

- "[with time](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with%20time)" and "[over time](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/over-time)" are a fixed phrases that mean "as time passes" or "[gradually](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gradually)" which means '*slowly over a period of time or a distance*'. Should be used without the definite article!

"**over the time**" can only be extended to "*over the course of time*" which means '*In or during the process of*'

Answer (score 1):

There are several prepositions that can be used before the word **time**. They are all employed to look at the future and mean much the same thing.

One can write that: The situation will get better..

> in time
>
> with time

and

> over time

But none of these take the article **the**. Its use changes the meaning of the expression:

> *With the time* for their departure nearing, they said their goodbyes.
>
> The test must be completed *in the time* allocated.